# How to query installed/recently ran aps in iOS for demographic purposes

Tags: xcode, ios, behavior

Is it possible to query 'installed apps', or recently ran applications in an iOS environment? Does Apple allow access to this level of user information? I'm interested in seeing a user's installed applications, so that I can be specific in targeting/providing relevant information.

ex. A user has Turbo Tax and CalculatorHD installed, they would find information on Tax Help/Services to be of benefit.

Comment: That would go against Apple protecting User's Privacy.

Answer (score 1):

You wish... I don't think an app designed to spam users is likely to ever get approved.

Comment: Just to be clear - no, there is no way to do that. (All apps run in a 'sandbox'!)